# Calling C# web service exposed on (soap.tcp) from Java

Tags: c#, java, url, soap, tcp

I found it is quite easy to create a .Net client to invoke a service with soap.tcp protocol.

```
Uri destinationUri = new Uri("soap.tcp://SomeHostName/SomePath");
Uri destinationUri = new Uri("http://SomeHostName/SomePath");
EndpointReference destination = new EndpointReference(destinationUri);
SoapSender sender = new SoapSender(destination);
```

But I need to create a Java client instead of a .Net client to the same URI  (soap.tcp://SomeHostName/SomePath). Is it possible with Java with this protocol (soap.tcp) to invoke a web service.

Also I found the same question is asked 
http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/879818-calling-c-web-service-soap-tcp-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can do that by implementing the "soap.tcp"-protocol as described by MS:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219293.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219210.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219175.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219190.aspx

I don't know of anyone having done that... so it will be a major undertaking... "soap.tcp" is NOT made for interoperability... SOAP over HTTP is interoperable and should be used in cases like yours...

Comment: Yes, you seem to be true, I also found this https://blogs.oracle.com/oleksiys/entry/how_to_make_web_service1. down the line somebody had tried the same and found out soap.tcp is MS specific protocol.